# Setting datacontext with prism

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-injection, prism, unity-container

I am trying to create a module with PRISM and right now I set the DataContext inside the View which means I can only use a Parameterless constructor, but that means I cant use dependency injection (I use Unity) in the constructor which I would like

If it is possible I would like neither the view or the vm to know each other and want to use something like

```
private void RegisterServices()
{
    var employeeViewModel = new EmployeeViewModel();

    _container.RegisterType<IEmployeeViewModel, EmployeeViewModel>();
    _container.RegisterType<EmployeeView>();

    EmployeeView.Datacontext = employeeViewModel;
}
```

Which I would register in the EmployeeModule

Is this possible or should I use code behind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may pass the interface of `ViewModel` to the `View` in the constructor. This way, `View` only knows the interface of `ViewModel` and `ViewModel` knows nothing about the `View`.

Ex.

```
public class EmployeeView : UserControl
{
    public EmployeeView(IEmployeeViewModel vm)
    {
         this.DataContext = vm; //// better to set the ViewModel in the Loaded method
    }
}
```

Refer to [this blog post](http://www.paulstovell.com/mvvm-instantiation-approaches) for multiple approaches of MVVM instantiation.

Comment: But its not possible to not have anything in the code behind?

Comment: you may create the ViewModel as a resource in the xaml; then you can not use the unity container. you may just create a base class for your views then you only need to inherit the base class in the code behind. You need to declare a relationship between ViewModel and View. Refer to the link in the question.

Answer (score 1):

[Prism documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405494%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx) gives you an option

> Often, you will find it useful to define a controller or service class
>   to coordinate the instantiation of the view and view model classes.
>   This approach can be used with a dependency injection container, such
>   as MEF or Unity, or when the view explicitly creates its required view
>   model.

For my module I would do the following
Create an interface for service inside module

```
public interface ICustomModuleUiService
{
    void ShowMainView();
    void ShowExtraView();
}
```

Production implementation in the same module:

```
class CustomModuleUiService : ICustomModuleUiService
{
    private readonly IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;

    public CustomModuleUiService(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
    {
        _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
    }

    public void ShowMainView()
    {
        var ddsViewModel = new DdsViewModel(_eventAggregator, this);
        DdsForm form = new DdsForm();
        form.DataContext = ddsViewModel;
        form.Show();
    }

    public void ShowExtraView()
    {
        //some code here
    }
}
```

And finally module code

```
[ModuleExport("DssModule", typeof(DssModuleImpl))]
public class DssModuleImpl : IModule
{
    private readonly IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;
    private ICustomModuleUiService _uiService;

    [ImportingConstructor]
    public DssModuleImpl(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
    {
        _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
        _uiService = new CustomModuleUiService(_eventAggregator);
    }

    public void Initialize()
    {
        _eventAggregator.GetEvent<OpenDdsFormEvent>().Subscribe(param => _uiService.ShowMainView());
    }
}
```

Using this approach I'll get

- ViewModel can be unit tested
- I can dynamically change the reaction on OpenDdsFormEvent by substituting implementation of ICustomModuleUiService